# how to display previously selected value in UIPickerview selected bar

Tags: iphone

I am displaying numbers from 0 to 30 in a [UIPickerview](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/82c3da83ab.png).

And call a pickerview when i tap on a button.

when ever i select one value in pickerview and tap on ok button to quit pickerview.

for the next time when ever i tap on button to open UIPickerview i need to display previous selected value [like this](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/6fa95eac9b.png).

for example previously i select 13 for the next time when i open pickerview i need to display 13 on selected bar as show in figure.

how can i done.

can any one please help me.

Thank u in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Save user selection somewhere and before you show your picker view set its selection programmatically with `selectRow:inComponent:animated:` method:

```
// Create picker if needed
[pickerView selectRow:13 inComponent:0 animated:NO];
// Now show the picker
```